# htaccess rewrite rule from subfolder to file.html

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, clean-urls

Im trying to rewrite-redirect a set of URLs like this

> From this: misitio.com/categoria1 --> To this -->
> misitio.com/categoria1.html

so far ive got one working match, this rewrites first level subfolder:

```
 RewriteRule ^categoria1/(\w+)$ $1.html [QSA,L]
```

My goal now is , given whatever subfolders deep the url input is, i'd rewrite the last subfolder as a single html file, like this:

> From this: misitio.com/categoria1/categoria2/categoria3 --> to this:
> misitio.com/categoria3.html
>
> From this: misitio.com/categoria1/categoria2/categoria3/categoria4/categoria5/
> --> To this --> misitio.com/categoria5.html

I know ive got to use conditionals, a little help here will be appreciated :D

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To rewrite 
- http://example.com/cat1cat2/cat3/cat4/cat/5/

to

- http://example.com/5.html

You can use the following RewriteRule :

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /$5.html [NC,L]
```

Comment: Thanks, thats exactly what i was looking for!